# Is there a way in SwiftUI to transport and handle data from an property to the class?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have two classes here. `Music` which is used to store music url and load metadata, and `MusicManager` which is used to store a list of music and sort them after loading of  all music's metadata finished.

Since the loading of metadata for each music `let metadata = try? await asset.load(.commonMetadata)` is asynchronous, I can't directly call sort function in `init()`.

I tried to find some solution using `Publisher` in Combine framework that when the metadata is loaded, the publisher will emit a completion, and if `MusicManager` received enough completion (same as music list's count), it will perform the sort.

```
class Music: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    static let publisher = PassthroughSubject<Void,Error>
......
}

class MusicManager: ObservableObject {
......
    static var count = 0
    let subscriber = Music.pub.sink { completion in
        switch completion {
        case .finished:
            count += 1
            if musicList.count == count {
                ......
            }
        case .failure(_):
        }
    } receiveValue: { _ in }
......
}
```

But it said `Instance member 'library' cannot be used on type 'MusicListManager'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?`

How can I am informed, when all music's metadata are already loaded. I would appreciate it if you can give me some advice.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't normally use `sink` with `ObservableObject`, instead we [`assign`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/assign(to:)) the end of the Combine pipeline to an `@Published` which also makes the lifetime of the pipeline the same as the object's, so there is no need to store cancellables.

However, you mentioned you are using async/await. If using that you don't need `ObservableObject` anymore. Just pass the asset into your `View` as a let param, and then use the [`task`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu/task(id:priority:_:)) modifier to call your async/await code and set an `@State` with the result which will cause `body` to be called. SwiftUI will calculate the `View` hierarchy diff and update the UIKit/AppKit views on screen with the changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to do is executing `sort()` method after all music are loaded. I think what you mentioned just displays music list on the `View`, which can not call `sort()` method automatically. How can I do this.

Comment: Or I came up with another idea. When each music is loaded (in `init()`), it informs `MusicManager` to insert it in the musicList. But I have no idea how can I do this. I would be appreciated if you can do me a favor.

Comment: Fetch and sort it in the async task